# Proof that conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})] = \mathbb{E}[X]$.

Tags: probability-theory

Given probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_0, \mathbb{P})$, and $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{F}_0$, the probability textboooks I have encountered so far seem to take for granted that the random variable given by conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})] = \mathbb{E}[X]$ a.s. . How would one go about proving this?

Here's my attempt at the proof, but I am currently stuck. Let $Y = \mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}) $. Then,
$$
\int_\Omega Y \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_\Omega Y (1_{\{Y\in \mathcal{F}\}} + 1_{\{Y \not \in \mathcal{F}\}}) \, d\mathbb{P}.
$$
By definition of conditional expectation and splitting up the integral, the first term on the right simply becomes
$$
\int_\Omega X 1_{\{X\in \mathcal{F}\}} \, d\mathbb{P}.
$$
However, I am having trouble with the second part. Since it's not in $\mathcal{F}$, how can I relate it back to $X$ again? More specifically, is there a way to show that the second part equates to  $\int_\Omega X 1_{\{X \not \in \mathcal{F}\}} \, d\mathbb{P}$?

Or should this be proved differently?

Comment: Expected value is a fixed constant. There's no need to say $E(E(X\mid \mathcal F)) = EX$ holds almost surely.

Comment: @AlvinLepik I think that's true in other cases, but if we take conditional expectation wrt a sigma algebra, the result is still a random variable

Comment: It makes sense to claim something like $E(X\mid\mathcal F) = X$ a.s. But when you integrate a random variable, it spits out a specific number.

Comment: yup thats true! i think i misread your first comment (have been preparing for my QE for the last 8 hours ><). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Y \in \mathcal F$ does not make sense. $Y$ is not a set so it cannot belong to a sigma algebra.

By definition of conditional expectation $\int_A YdP=\int_A XdP$ for any set $A \in \mathcal F$ and taking $A=\Omega$ we get $EY=EX$.

Comment: thanks! wow this is simple, i completely forgot about the last fact :)